# Error to Login using Facebook Unity SDK + Android, only when the Facebook App is installed in the Device

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, android-facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the "Facebook SDK 5.1" with "Unity 4.5.2 - Mac version" to Build my Android App.

The App was successfully builded, but I can only execute "Facebook Login" if the "Facebook App" is not installed in the device.

When the Facebook App is installed, after I input my FB Account and go back to my App, it is not logged in the Facebook, but when the Facebook App is not installed, it works perfectly.

Someone here already have faced this problem?

Here is my App to you test (Test Login with and without Facebook App installed):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SandolkakosDigital.EoParaibaWORLD

Thanks,
Marllon Brando.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I had to do 2 things:

A) Use only the "email" and "publish_actions" in the Facebook Login Scope. So, now I do Login in Facebook like this:

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions", callback);
```

B) The "Key Hash" generated in the Unity Engine was wrong. So, now I am generating the Key Hash through the steps:

```
1. Unzip .apk file and extract META-INF\CERT.RSA file
2. In the Prompt, run: keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
3. notice SHA1 bytes are printed like 29:37:F1:CB:06…
4. copy SHA1 bytes into HEX to BASE64 converter (http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
5. see your BASE64 key hash in output field
```

I know other developers are passing by these problems too. So I hope my steps can help them :D

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove this aar ( which is duplicated in FB SDK with android SDK )

Assets\Plugins\Android\support-v4-25.3.1.aar